# How to select specific files from a .txt and create a folder

Tags: python, directory

I´ve a .txt file which has the following structure inside it:

```
2   PNEUMONIA/person888_bacteria_2812.jpeg
2   PNEUMONIA/person1209_bacteria_3161.jpeg
2   PNEUMONIA/person1718_bacteria_4540.jpeg
2   PNEUMONIA/person549_bacteria_2303.jpeg
2   PNEUMONIA/person831_bacteria_2742.jpeg
2   PNEUMONIA/person1571_bacteria_4108.jpeg
1   COVID-19/4-x-day1.jpg
0   HEALTHY/IM-0486-0001.jpeg
```

Furthermore, there are three folders:

- Covid: Contains images of lungs with coronavirus
- Pneumonia: Contains images of lungs with pneumonia
- Healthy: Contains images with healthy lungs.

I would need to create a folder containing the images specified in this .txt file. Therefore, my question is how can I read the .txt file and move the images from these folders to a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read the .txt file :

```py
file = open("path to the file", "r") #r is for read
mylist = file.readlines() #each line will be a new element of mylist
file.close() #don't forget to close it
```

So now if you do `print(mylist)` you get :

```
["2   PNEUMONIA/person888_bacteria_2812.jpeg", "2   PNEUMONIA/person1209_bacteria_3161.jpeg", "2   PNEUMONIA/person1718_bacteria_4540.jpeg", "2   PNEUMONIA/person549_bacteria_2303.jpeg", "2   PNEUMONIA/person831_bacteria_2742.jpeg", "2   PNEUMONIA/person1571_bacteria_4108.jpeg", "1   COVID-19/4-x-day1.jpg", "0   HEALTHY/IM-0486-0001.jpeg"]
```

So you can loop over all the elements with a for loop... Then how to create the folder and the files ?

To create the folder :

```py
import os
dirName = 'your_path'
try:
    os.mkdir(dirName)
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ") 
except FileExistsError:
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")
```

This will create a folder, but won't do it if it already exists.

Then, move the files :

```py
import shutil, os
for f in mylist:
    shutil.move(f, dirName)
```

With dirName in the precedent code.
So the full code looks like :

```py
import shutil, os
file = open("path to the file", "r")
mylist = file.readlines()
file.close()
dirName = 'your_path'
try:
    os.mkdir(dirName)
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
    for f in mylist:
        shutil.move(f, dirName)
except FileExistsError:
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")
```

But, if we consider your file :

```
2   PNEUMONIA/person888_bacteria_2812.jpeg
2   PNEUMONIA/person1209_bacteria_3161.jpeg
2   PNEUMONIA/person1718_bacteria_4540.jpeg
2   PNEUMONIA/person549_bacteria_2303.jpeg
2   PNEUMONIA/person831_bacteria_2742.jpeg
2   PNEUMONIA/person1571_bacteria_4108.jpeg
1   COVID-19/4-x-day1.jpg
0   HEALTHY/IM-0486-0001.jpeg
```

Maybe the first characters, those numbers, aren't desired in the name of the file ?
Then just search for split method and have fun !

Warning about moving the files :

When we do :

```py
for f in mylist:
    shutil.move(f, dirName)
```

We are assuming that the script is in the same location as the pictures, so it takes just f as the path and it is good. But if it is located anywhere else, you should do something like :

```py
for f in mylist:
    shutil.move("path_to_the_original_folder_+_an_\_at_the_end"+f, dirName)
```

For exemple :

```py
for f in mylist:
    shutil.move("C:\Covid\"+f, dirName)
```

There it is !

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
# source folder such as '.' or os.getcwd(), etc.
src ='source path' 

# desitination folder such as '.' or os.getcwd(), etc.         
dst = 'destination folder'  

with open('file.txt') as file:
  for line in file:
    # Get parent folder and filename
    # such as PNEUMONIA/person888_bacteria_2812.jpeg"
    relative_path = line.rstrip().split(' ', 1)[1].strip()

    # Full source path (prepend src to relative path)
    src_path = os.path.join(src, relative_path)

    # Destination folder
    destination = os.path.join(dst, path)

    # make directory if it does not exists
    # Path(destination).parent is parent folder of
    # destination
    os.makedirs(Path(destination).parent, exist_ok = True)

    # Move file 
    shutil.move(src_path, destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
import shutil
new_path = (r"C:\your\new\path")
file = open(r"C:\your\list\path\list.txt","r")
read_lines= file.readlines()
file.close()
for path in read_lines:
    shutil.copy(path.replace("\n",""),new_path)
```

make sure the paths look like this in your list:

```
C:\like\this\path\filename.jpeg
C:\like\this\path\filename.jpeg
C:\like\this\path\filename.jpeg
C:\like\this\path\filename.jpeg
```